# What defined the frequency of a pulse if not its periodicity?

Tags: optics, waves, fourier-transform, frequency, spectroscopy

When reading about time-domain spectroscopies, it is stated that via the Fourier transformation of a pulse we can obtain its frequency domain information (as you can see in the figures below). This contradicts my instinctive idea of frequency, which is one of repetition.

[image] [image]

I have always understood that the frequency is the inverse of the period of repetition of a signal, in other words and if depicting a pulsed signal, its frequencies would be defined as the number of pulses per second.

[image]

So, how can a single pulse have a so many different frequencies within itself, [as shown by the Fourier transformation of a signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terahertz_time-domain_spectroscopy)?

Answer (score 4):

> I have always understood that the frequency is the inverse of the period of repetition of a signal

That is the definition of the *fundamental* frequency.

IDK the proper name of the theorem, but it has been proven that any periodic function can be decomposed into an infinite series of pure sinusoidal functions having frequencies that are integer multiples of the fundamental frequency.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series

The mathematical operation that relates a periodic function to the coefficients of its Fourier series is called "[Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)."

Given [digital samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal) of one full period of a waveform, there exist algorithms that can find the coefficients of a *finite* Fourier series for a waveform that gives the same samples when digitized. Such an algorithm is called a [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT), and a subset of those algorithms are known as [fast Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) (FFT).

Answer (score 0):

An *infinite* long sinusoid, such as $A_x\cos(\omega_x t +\phi_x)$ is characterized by its frequency $\omega_x$ and amplitude $A_x$. The phase $\phi_x$ here just means a point in time referencing where we set the zero transitions, say. The moment you shorten the infinite long sinusoid to a finite length it is not periodic and has not a well-defined *frequency*. But certain measuring instruments can still extract *that* frequency the pulse it would have were it infinitely long and periodic. For example, a *correlator* is one such instrument.

This is how it works. You take a sinusoidal signal generator that has two outputs, $r_c(t)=A_0\cos(\omega_c t +\phi_0)$ and $r_s(t)=A_0\sin(\omega_c t +\phi_0)$. Let the pulse length be $T_p$ and extend in $t\in \mathcal I =[-T_p/2,T_p/2]$. Now multiply this unknown frequency pulse $x(t)$ by $r_c$ and $r_s$ and integrate the result over  the interval $\mathcal I$:

$$a_c = \frac{1}{T_p}\int_{\mathcal I}  x(t) r_c(t)dt= \frac{1}{T_p}\int_{-\frac{T_p}{2}}^{\frac{T_p}{2}} A_x \cos(\omega_xt+\phi_x) A_0\cos(\omega_c t +\phi_0)dt\\
=A_0A_x \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\sin(\pi(u_x+u_0) T_p+\phi_x+\phi_0)}{\pi(u_x+u_0)T_p}+\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x+u_0) T_p - \phi_x -\phi_0)}{\pi(u_x+u_0)T_p}\\
+\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x- u_0) T_p+\phi_x -\phi_0)}{\pi(u_x - u_0)T_p}
+\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x-u_0) T_p -\phi_x+\phi_0)}{\pi(u_x -u_0)T_p}\right) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Here $\omega = 2\pi u$ and unless $x\approx 0 $ the ratio $\sin(x)/x \approx 0$, so for large $u_0T_p$ the first two terms in $\eqref{1}$ is insignificant compared to the last two terms, and you get that

$$a_c \approx
A_0A_x \cos(\phi_x -\phi_0)\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x- u_0) T_p)}{\pi(u_x - u_0)T_p}
 \tag{2}\label{2}$$
For the correlation with $r_s$ the result is very similar
$$a_s \approx
A_0A_x \sin(\phi_x -\phi_0)\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x- u_0) T_p)}{\pi(u_x - u_0)T_p}
 \tag{3}\label{3}$$
The correlator measures the sum square of these two:
$$p(\omega_0)=a_c^2+a_s^2=A_0^2A_x^2 \left(\frac{\sin(\pi(u_x- u_0) T_p)}{\pi(u_x - u_0)T_p}\right)^2
 \tag{4}\label{4}$$ which reaches maximum when $\omega_0=\omega_x$, that is $$p_{max}=p(\omega_x)=A_0^2A_x^2 \tag{5}\label{5}.$$

To measure the frequency of a sinusoid pulse of an unknown *frequency* we correlate the signal with $r_c$ and $r_s$ for a fixed reference $\omega_0$ and the calculate the sum square $p$ of the resulting correlations. Then we change the correlator's reference frequency to maximize $p$. The unknown frequency is estimated as the reference that maximizes $p$. Notice that we need to know both the *length* $T_p$ of the pulse and its timing that is when it starts or ends to correlate it properly. Both the timing and the length are usually unknown but must be estimated and it is usually done by stepping thorough at various values as the frequency estimation itself is done.